# using slider change the volume in AVAudioPlayer in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am using this code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
player.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (player == nil)
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);             
else 
    [player play];
```

but i want to change the volume so how can i get the volume detail?

Answer (score 3):

Set up your UISlider. Register it to receive the ValueChanged events in IB or programmatically. Set its min value to 0 and max to 100. And that should be it.

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
  myPlayer.volume = slider.value / 100.0;
}
```