# volume control slider like as how we increase or decrease the volume in sound bars or speakers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to do volume control slider like how we increase or decrease the volume in sound bars or speakers.I am searching for that but i did not get any solution.Can you give me advice on how to do it or provide any sample example.

Comment: https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGVolumeControl try this

Comment: Have you tried using a UISlider?

Comment: @KaylaGalway : I tried with  UISlider but those are all circular manner but i need how the device we increase or decrease the volume.

Comment: Well you haven't posted any code, so I'm not sure if you trying to do this for an AVAudioPlayer, but if you are it is pretty easy. This previous answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795624/using-slider-change-the-volume-in-avaudioplayer-in-iphone-sdk

Or you can just use an MPVolumeView which controls system volume. Another answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601551/how-to-control-ios-system-volume-using-a-uislider

Comment: @ Bhumit Muchhadia :thanks for reply. i tried but not required one.any other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution .

Please refer

1.https://github.com/hollance/MHRotaryKnob/

2.https://github.com/ajgr/CircularSlider

first one helped me.